# Resizing image in HTML and keep CSS absolute right

Tags: html, css

I've got another question that I'm having trouble finding out the answer. I have a profile image that is huge, and I want to put a scaled down version of this picture in the top right of my navbar (similar to how StackOverflow has)

I'm running into a problem. It seems as though when I resize the image in the HTML code, the image no longer "obeys" the CSS rule to be at the absolute position, right 0%. Why is this?

Codepin: https://codepen.io/dansbyt/pen/bGpaPRj

CSS & HTML in question:

```css
.profile{
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  right: 0%;}
.navbar{
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 56px;
  z-index: 10;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #5B7042;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #3F5328}
  .profile img{float:right}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="profile">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://mrdansby.com/Resources/ProfilePics/default.png" style="width:4%;border-radius: 50%"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Info: You forgot to close the 1st div

Comment: Even doing this does not fix the problem.

Comment: just apply float:right to your img element. Position absolute wont respect your parent div rules

Comment: That works great for the positioning, but then if I later make this a link, then the entire area to the left of the image becomes a clickable link too

Comment: it depends where you will put your `a` element. You can share more code. I posted an answer, I can update it based on your code.

Comment: I updated the code and the CodePin. Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Look my answer, I updated it and added a div next to your a element, and only the image is a link, nothing on the left of it will be. I also removed this position absolute because you dont need that

Comment: @MaxiGui Tried that, no such luck. Uploaded a new Codepin to replicate the issue. https://codepen.io/dansbyt/pen/ZEWvdwG

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221115/discussion-between-maxigui-and-trae).

Comment: answered updated. But I will recommand you to check bootstrap 4 for a solution more responsive and flexible

Answer (score 0):

Position absolute is not going to respect the parent size anymore.

> absolute The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no
> space is created for the element in the page layout. It is positioned
> relative to its closest positioned ancestor, if any; otherwise, it is
> placed relative to the initial containing block. Its final position is
> determined by the values of top, right, bottom, and left. This value
> creates a new stacking context when the value of z-index is not auto.
> The margins of absolutely positioned boxes do not collapse with other
> margins.

More info: [Position info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

I reworked on your codepen to fit with your expectation, but I will recommand to not use it as it is not flexible / responsive. I would recommand you to use bootstrap for this kind of element which is doing a great job.

- [Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/)
- [Bootstrap 4 navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/)

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  padding-top: 60px;
}
a.logo, a.logo img{
  height: 100%;  
}
a.logo{
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: .3125rem;
  padding-bottom: .3125rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  line-height: inherit;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.nav-container{
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 100%;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: -webkit-box!important;
  display: -ms-flexbox!important;
  display: flex!important;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: auto;
  flex-basis: auto;
}
.money{
  /*position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  right: 6%;*/
  margin-right:30px;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
  font-size: x-large;
  color: white;
}
.profile{
  
}
img.profile {
  float:right;
}
.navbar{
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 56px;
  z-index: 10;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #5B7042;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #3F5328;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-flow: row nowrap;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  -webkit-box-pack: start;
  -ms-flex-pack: start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.navbar_links{
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: auto auto auto 0;
}
  .navbar_links a{
    padding: 1% 1%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
    font-size: x-large;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
.navbar_links2{
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}
  .navbar_links a:hover {background-color: #3F5328}
  .navbar_links span{position:relative; bottom:5px}
.navbar_links2 a{
  width:40px;
  display:block;
}
.navbar_links2 a img{
  max-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a class="logo" href="../index.php"><img src="http://mrdansby.com/Resources/logo.png" style="width:auto;"></a>
  <div class="nav-container">
    <ul class="navbar_links">
      <li>
        <a href="../index.php"><img style="width:30%" src="http://mrdansby.com/projects/i_house.png"><span> Dash</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="navbar_links2" style="margin-right:0;">
      <div class="money">$100</div>
      <a href="#"><img class="profile" src="http://mrdansby.com/Resources/ProfilePics/default.png"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

according to your implementation, you have to define the image width exact measurements not like 4%, for example try changing this 4% to 40px and test it should work fine

Answer (score 0):

CSS is superior against HTML, so if you set attribute height/width in html like

```
<img src="..." width="150">
```

And then use CSS

```
img {
width: 300px;
```

}

The image will be 300px and html attribute will be ignored.

You shouldn't mix inline CSS with external CSS, if not necessary (for example while css is generated via back-end (PHP), background images etc.)

Your problem is, that you are not positioning image as well, but his wrapper -> .profile
You should rewrite

```
.profile {  position: absolute;  top: 15%;  right: 0%;}
```

to

```
.profile img{  position: absolute;  top: 15%;  right: 0%;}
```